# pgfplots: How to color inside a 2D polygon based on x and y values

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to fill the inside of a polygon with a gradient of color. The color should vary from the lowest values of an expression (e.g., `5x + 6y`) to the highest values of the same expression inside the area of the polygon. I looked around and found the `surf` plot, but it seems like it is for 3D only and if I try to use it, then my axis get 3D and trash my whole image. In the 2D plot types none seems to do quite what I want, scatter plots are multiple points (not an area), and mesh plots color a line (not an area again). Page 145 of the pgfplots manual has some plots like I want (2D color gradients) except their shape is not clipped by a polygon and their color is not defined by a function of `x` and `y`.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: You should always show what you have tried - with compilable code. Otherwise the question will be closed or lie unanswered like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[
regular polygon, regular polygon sides=5,
minimum size=4cm, inner sep=0pt,
draw, thick,
path picture={
\path;
\begin{axis}[
anchor=center,
width=4cm, height=4cm, scale only axis,
view={0}{90},
xmin=-1, xmax=1,
ymin=-1, ymax=1, 
hide axis,
]
\addplot3[
surf, shader=interp,
domain=-1:1, samples=20,
y domain=-1:1, samples y=20,
point meta=5*x+6*y
] (x,y,0);
\end{axis}
}]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Shaded pentagon in blue, red and yellow tones]